# how to retain fixed positions of elements inside transformed elements?

Tags: html, css, transform

it's a known 'bug' that elements with fixed position loose their position if the container is translated. For example, if i've got a structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

and, say, the container is scrolled, when the conteiner gets transformed (say, translate(x,y), rotate(), or so..), then the fixed element behaves like it was positioned relative and it scrolls with the container. I can see it on the latest firefox, for example.

How can one fix this kind of problem? Is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not a bug. It's actually [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-2d-transforms-20091201/#introduction) recommended behaviour.
(See [this post by Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/), or this question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115880/css-transform-translate-moves-postionfixed-inner-div) which accepted solution only provides a link to the same meyer's post)

For those who don't know this issue, and because you didn't provide a snippet into your question, here's one.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('container').classList.toggle('transformed')
}, false);
```

```css
#bg {
  border: 1px solid #AFA;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid #FAF;
  height: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  background: rgba(125, 175, 0, .7);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.transformed {
  transform: translate(0, 5em);
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="container" class="transformed">
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    this is a scrollable paragraph
    <br>.<br>the "fixed" content does scroll with the paragraph
    <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    you can click to toggle the transformation On/Off
    <br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    <span id="content">relatively fixed content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I did find something that may help others facing the same issue.
**It's not really a solution,** since the *"fixed"* element will be only inside the container, (*except for IE browsers where it will really be fixed to the document*). But in my case, it's actually what I wanted and maybe it'll be fine for others too.

If you add a wrapper, set its `height:100%; width:100%;` and `overflow:auto`, then your *"fixed"* content *won't scroll with the container*.

Actually it's not you container which scrolls anymore, but the wrapper. So you might want to set the container's `overflow:visible` or `hidden` to avoid unwanted scrolling of *the not so well* "fixed" element.
Also, note that you need your wrapper be a `block` or `inline-block` element.

```css
#bg {
  border: 1px solid #AFA;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid #FAF;
  height: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  background: rgba(125, 175, 0, .7);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.transformed {
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="container" class="transformed">
    <div id="wrapper">
      .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
      <span id="content">relatively fixed content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this bug, but when you use `positioned: fixed;` the element is positioned relative to the browser window, so it doesn't really make any sense to put it inside a container.
This markup would be my recommendation:

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: not always. My case is that of an header bar that must scroll with the container only till a certain amount, than a part of it is setted fixed. The container is also absolute positioned. You know, that kind of things. Being building also an off-canvas on the same page, I need to use translate3D on the container.

Answer (score -1):

Once you use `position: fixed;` on any element it is positioned relative to the view-port. Directly from [page in MDN about position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

> **fixed**
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled.

So what you are experiencing is a what it is actually supposed to work like and not a 'bug'.

Now if what you want is something that is positioned with relation to the `.container` div and translate with it than you will have to use `absolute` positioning here. Take a look at  [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vabhdman/f59no8vu/). The important CSS is-

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Notice that with positioning the inner div as `absolute` I have also positioned the outer div as `relative` as the inner div takes its position in reference to the closest parent div positioned as anything different from `static`.

Comment: Hi, thank you but that's not exactly my case, see my comment above. I know fixed elements should stay out, but this is an hybrid one (it changes). So I need a fixed element inside a [positioned+scrolled+translated] element, and the fixed one must be always fixed as it should.

Comment: So when you say hybrid do you mean that it should be positioned normally for some part and position fixed after a certain part ? Please explain this in a little detail because once you use `fixed` on anything it doesn't matter what you do with the parent container.