# iOS Safari HTML5 Video overlays everything

Tags: ios, angular, html, html5-video, mobile-safari

I'm writing an app which uses html5 video elements.
On iOS Safari when using `playsinline` to ensure the video is treated as an inline element for positioning etc, it works as expected **except** that the video appears **on top of everything**.  `z-index` and positioning techniques don't seem to help with this issue.  I cannot get anything to appear on top of the video under any circumstances.

On every browser except iOS Safari this seems to work absolutely fine.

For reference, this is an Angular app, and I'm currently testing in Mobile Safari on iOS 11.1.2

Also worth mentioning, the video `src` will resolve to a local **blob** url.  eg. `blob:file:///2afb998a-84e3-4819-8243-5da7d7da3cb6`

```
<video
   id="video"
   [src]="src"
   autoplay="autoplay"
   muted="muted"
   webkit-playsinline
   playsinline>
</video>
```

Comment: Without html and css it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing `overflow` style from parent *div* of `video` tag solved it. See [Video and z-index inside scaled element: some divs disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653475/video-and-z-index-inside-scaled-element-some-divs-disappear) for more information.