How to make z-index work with sticky header
I have a footer that need to go on top of a sticky header.
Unfortunately it doesn't work, despite them being on the same level markup etc.
The snippet below seems to work? But not the exact same code in safari.
If i resize the window after page load it seems to sometimes update and work. Bug?
Any ideas on this would be appreciated!!


#header{
position: sticky;
top:0;
background-color: red;
z-index: 1;
height:60vh

}

#footer{
position:relative;
background-color: yellow;
z-index: 100;
height:60vh


}
  <div id=header>
  Hello world
  </div>
  
  <div id="footer">
    Hello world

  </div>




If you can post more complete HTML structure that will help. As you mentioned, z-index is dependent on the items being on the same level so it's possible that the nesting isn't exactly right. If it's an intermittent problem, you can also try adding this rule to both elements:  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);. This was the solve for an old question about video z-index problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653475/video-and-z-index-inside-scaled-element-some-divs-disappear/49885529#49885529

funny, the translateZ(0) dit it, any idea why?

It's just a known glitch with Safari's rendering engine that they refuse to patch. Safari is out of date garbage and is to development today what IE8 was 10 years ago, the first and only thing anyone with an Apple device should use Safari for is installing a real browser.

This question is similar to: Z-Index not working on Safari - fine on Firefox and Chrome. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

the z-index for the footer is kinda much; try reducing it

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
